# How to set the max characters per column field to specify the maximum length of data displayed in a single column in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

In my table I have a column of type "json". This json data is up to 10MB big. It takes a lot of time to render such an amount of data in PgAdmin 4. Even if my table consists just of one row the rendering process is between 5 and 10 seconds.

In PgAdmin 3 there is a possibility to set the "Max characters per column" https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/options-query_tool.html

But where to define that in PgAdmin 4?